# Working paper to published paper

Tags: publications, online-publication

I have a couple working papers on ssrn.com that I am preparing for submission to a journal.  If it is accepted, should I pull the ssrn.com copy from the website or block people's access to it by making it private?  Is there either a duty from the copyright change to remove it or if there is no legal obligation is there an ethical one?

Answer (score 1):

Their [FAQs](https://www.ssrn.com/en/index.cfm/ssrn-faq/#no_restrict) section states:

> **10. Does submission to SSRN restrict in any way what I can do with my paper?**
>   No. And if at any time you wish to immediately remove a paper from SSRN, you may do it yourself through SSRN HQ, or contact us to remove it for you.

[Contacting](https://www.ssrn.com/en/index.cfm/contactus/) them is always an option to make sure though.

Comment: Yes, but the question wasn't "can I remove it," but rather do I have a duty to remove it?

Comment: Yes but the answer is not "can you remove it" either. It is very clearly written "AND if you want to remove it". So they say that you can do anything you want with your paper as fas as they're concerned.